# how to check a php file every 10 second using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, load

I hava a php file for check the Items id

for example `check.php`:

```
<?php

if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'])))
{
     echo "This Id: $_GET['id'] is <b>true</b> \n\n";
}
else
{
     echo "This Id: $_GET['id'] is <b>true</b> \n\n";
}

?>
```

Every 10 seconds, I want to check the IDs using JavaScript.

```
<script>
var id1 = 1;
var id2 = 2;
var id3 = 5;
var id4 = 9;
var id5 = 10;
var id6 = 23;
</script>
```

I don't know how to use JavaScript or AJAX.

I want my output to be like this:

```
//after 10 seconds 
This Id: 1 is true

//after 20 seconds
This id: 2 is true

//after 30 seconds
This id: 5 is trud

and ....
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you look around, you'll find tons of examples of Ajax calls.  Look into setTimeout();, specifically for the timed/repeated calls.

Answer (score 0):

use setInterval for the interval and then jQuery $.load specifying some variable arguments attached to the file to load from... eg $('body').load('file.php?id=2&time=2');

Comment: please get me codes of this. I ma bigginer in proggraming. Thanks all friends